# Vim - Get Current Directory

Tags: gvim

I'm currently adding a little bit of Git functionality to my menu.vim file, and for using a certain command (Gitk) I need to find out Vim's current directory.

How does one do that and include it in a command? (i.e. `:!echo "%current-directory"`)

---

I'll admit here that I asked the wrong question - but I figured it out.

I'm currently using these in my menu.vim:

```
function g:Gitk()
  :!cd $(dirname %); gitk
endfun

function g:GitGui()
  :!cd $(dirname %); git gui
endfun
```

Comment: I removed the "active-directory" tag, it has a different meaning.

Comment: If you're running a shell command, the current directory is in the shell variable `$PWD`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think either `:pwd` or `getcwd()` is what you are looking for.

---

Just to help memorize things:

`:pwd` => print working directory

`getcwd()` => get current working directory